# Serial output of Python images

Tags: python, image, imshow, imread

How can I render images sequentially in Spyder? At the moment, it turns out to display only the last image

```
from skimage.io import imread, imshow

img_5 = imread('C:/abc1.png')
imshow(img_5)

img_6 = imread('C:/abc2.png')
imshow(img_6)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this with `from IPython.display import display` like below:

```
from IPython.display import display, Image

for img in ['C:/abc1.png', 'C:/abc2.png']:
    ima = Image(filename=img , width=300,height=200)
    display(ima)
```

If you want to use `imshow` you can use `plt.imshow` like below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.io import imread, imshow


img_5 = imread('C:/abc1.png')
plt.imshow(img_5)
plt.show()

img_6 = imread('C:/abc2.png')
plt.imshow(img_6)
plt.show()
```

You can do this with `opencv-python` like below *(if you didn't have installed opencv try this code : `pip install opencv-python`)*

```
import cv2
for img in ['C:/abc1.png', 'C:/abc2.png']:
    im = cv2.imread(img)
    im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    plt.imshow(im)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not try it in spyder, but you can check:

```
imshow(img_5, block=False)
```

Do not use `block=False` in the last plot, otherwise the plots are closed when the script is finished.

Comment: I see ```AttributeError: 'AxesImage' object has no property 'block'```

Comment: How are you running your script? Maybe the solution is not to set the block parameter. But also import `from skimage.io import show` and use `show` after your `imshow` command.

Comment: I tried it but I see the same result